# How to call the python function in my html button

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, google-drive-api

```python
# DOWNLOAD DRIVE FILE BY ID
def baixar_arquivo_por_id(id_drive, caminho_download):
   try:
      credenciales = login()
      arquivo = credenciales.CreateFile({'id': id_drive})
      nome_arquivo = arquivo['title']
      arquivo.GetContentFile(caminho_download + nome_arquivo)
      print('Enviado com sucesso')

      if __name__ == "__main__":
         id_drive = '0B6t4W9IgqAU4Z2'
         caminho_download = '/Desktop/'
         baixar_arquivo_por_id(id_drive, caminho_download)

   except:
      print('Caminho ou arquivo estão incorreto ou não existe')

   return{'baixar_arquivo_por_id': baixar_arquivo_por_id}
```

Hello devs, I'm new to python, I did the integration of google drive in the project, everything is already working, I log in, I can download the file from the drive, the question is, my function is inside the context_processors file (where the code is), I wanted to call the python function in my html button to execute the code (eg when pressed, clicked, it would execute the python function). Someone give me a light?
I'm using the Django framework
my code

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is executed in the web-browser of the user, while your Python is executed on the server, presumably two different machines. So, the HTML code cannot execute your Python code, but your HTML code can contain some Javascript code that sends an [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) request to the server. It will probably be a POST request. Your AJAX request will be an HTTP request, so you will need to read about [the way you can handle HTTP requests in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/).

Once you implement the request in Django and it sends the proper response, you can induce it using your Javascript code.